# JQuery PhoneUS validation not working properly

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a field using JQuery validation PhoneUS. It does not work properly. It validates some phone numbers properly, but sometimes it's not working. My JSP is below.

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    }
  }
});
```

Html Code is:

```
<form id="myform">
  <label for="field">Required, us phone number: </label>
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

It validates properly this kind of numbers like 882282****. But sometimes this is not working properly for this kind of numbers like 801121****. When I am puting this kind of numbers I am getting this message "Please specify a valid phone number".

Please help me out

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan#Numbering_system), the "central office exchange code" (the second group of three numbers), `121` in your case, **cannot** start with `0` or `1`.   In other words, the `phoneUS` rule ***is*** working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think `801121****` is not valid in phoneus regular expression See http://jqueryvalidation.org/phoneUS-method/

The below code used for validating US Phone number,

```
//http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js
a.validator.addMethod('phoneUS', function (a, b) {
    return a = a.replace(/\s+/g, ''),
    this.optional(b) || a.length > 9 && a.match(/^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9])\)|[2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9]))-?[2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9])-?\d{4}$/)
}, 'Please specify a valid phone number'),
```

If it is valid then you can create your own [custom method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to validate it

Comment: thanks for your valuable information. The phone number is valid but somehow it's not getting validated through JQuery PhoneUS validation. So, I have to make my own custome method.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan#Numbering_system), the "central office exchange code" (the second group of three numbers), `121` in your case, **cannot** start with `0` or `1`.   In other words, the `phoneUS` rule ***is*** working properly.